# Unable to instantiate activity:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, instantiation, runtimeexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.joericharduz.akita/com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Code is like this:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
    if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
        cursor = myDataBase.query(true, GL_TABLE, new String[] { GL_ID,
                GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE }, GL_FK + " like '%" + inputText
                + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);

    } else {
        cursor = myDataBase.query(true, GL_TABLE, new String[] { GL_ID,
                GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE }, GL_VALUE + " like '%"
                + inputText + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    String[] columns = new String[] { GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvWord, R.id.tvMeaning, R.id.tvKanji };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.listword,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    ListView listView = mainActivity.wordlist;
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the
            // result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
            String countryCode = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("code"));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html). It takes data from SQLite database and puts into listview. When I tried to test this it gave error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity. No idea what may cause this problem. Please give some suggestions how to solve this problem.

Full stacktrace:

```
    08-05 21:36:01.375: W/dalvikvm(2367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.joericharduz.akita/com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
08-05 21:36:01.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     ... 11 more
08-05 21:37:13.851: W/dalvikvm(2579): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.joericharduz.akita/com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
08-05 21:37:13.937: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: pls post the full stacktrace

Comment: That stacktrace might have some line numbers that will help pinpoint where the reference to null happened.

Comment: Better yet, look at your logcat and double-click on the exception to be taking right to the NPE. Then fix it.

Comment: What is line 20 `MainActivity.java`? Why are you doing this `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity()`?.

Comment: Excuse me, what is NPE? When I double clicked nothing happening

Comment: @Raghunandan It is reference for MainActivity class inside DataBaseHelper class. It was used to get reference to listview by id: cannot include list by findviewbyid inside DataBaseHelper class

Comment: @JoeRichard NPE is NullPointerException ie something on that line is null. Your initializations fails. What are you trying to do `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity() ListView listView = mainActivity.wordlist`?. Totally wrong. You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Comment: In your MainActivity `DataBaseHelper  db = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this)` then  `Cursor curdor = db.getAllData()` then use the cursor in MainActivity to populate your listview. Have `getAllData()` in your helper class and return cursor.

Comment: @Raghunandan Trying to get listview by its id through Mainactivity because I could not get it in DataBaseHelper class. What you suggest to do?

Comment: @JoeRichard check my previous comment

Comment: @Raghunandan Created method searchWord which returns Cursor type. How to get returned cursor in MainActivity. For example in: dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listword,
     **cursor**, columns, to, 0); Here **cursor** is marked as error.

Comment: `DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this) then Cursor cursor = db.searchWord()`. Makes ure you return the cursor in `searchword`.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks a bunch :D You helped much :D Appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `MainActivity.java` at line 20. Since the NPE (NullPointerException) is happening when you make a call to findViewById, this is probably because you are calling findViewById on a NULL Activity, or on an Activity that has a NULL window (the implementation of findViewById in AOSP is just calling getWindow().findViewById()).

Double-check that you're only calling findViewById() when your Activity is in the correct state. Namely, you should wait until you get an `onCreate` callback before trying to do anything that has to do with windows or views.

Also, instantiating an Activity with something like `new MainActivity()` is extremely strange and is likely not to work unless you're trying to accomplish something really unusual and advanced.

Comment: calling findViewById on a NULL Activity. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer Exception is the most beautiful exception ever we can see. Find which line make this NPE, then backtrack! its sure you called something on a NULL OBJECT!!